# WooCommerce - Изменить формат вывода размера

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет, такой вопрос, могу ли я изменить формат вывода размера вариативного товара? Сейчас он выводится в виде `ширина х высота х диаметр см`. Есть ли какой-то фильтр для этого, а то я почему-то найти не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вставьте такой сниппет в function.php вашей темы:

```
function woocommerce_format_dimensions_filter( $dimension_string, $dimensions ) {
    // Ваш код

    return $dimension_string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'woocommerce_format_dimensions_filter', 10, 2 );
```

В фильтр передаются: текущая строка $dimension_string вида `40 x 20 x 10 cm` и массив размерностей $dimension.

Comment: Отлично, но есть 1 проблемка, если сделать так:
$string = "<div>".$dimensions['width']."</div>" 
return $string; (например)
то оно возвращает в виде строки, а не ДОМ. Есть какие-то мысли по этому поводу ?

Comment: так не получится, потому что в файле `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php` в строке 36 применяется esc_html к вашей строке. Вам надо этот шаблон скопировать в свою тему, чтобы получился такой путь `wp-content/themes/моя-тема/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php` и поправить этот шаблон.

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня особый случай. Мне нужно вытянуть с "Характеристики" товара ДхШхВ и поставить в нужное место (а именно в файл `/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`). Я сделал это путем добавления блока `<span class="product_dimensions"></span>`, куда по классу `.product_dimensions` вставляется значение при смене вариации товара (размера например). По этому править таблицу атрибутов не поможет. Может есть другой выход решения моей проблемы.

Comment: Я и забыл, что у вас вариативный товар. Но из вашего последнего комментария ничего не понял. Покажите свой код variable.php

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ctiki/9fd0e8c987766b93f40974ec67a1d2e9

`<span class="product_dimensions"></span>` - Сюда подтягивается строка с размерами. Я так понимаю это делается с помощью JS и поиск идет по классу (.product_dimensions).

Comment: туда пишется так: this.text( this.attr( 'data-o_content' ) ); попробуйте при формировании php записать в атрибут data-o_content то, что нужно